# error with stream_socket_client

Tags: php, ios, ssl, push-notification

Why am I getting this errors:

> Warning: stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1.
>   OpenSSL Error messages: error:14094410:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
>
> Warning: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto
>
> Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to
>   ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error)
>   Failed to connect: 0

I am sending this php page with a cron job and the code error is referring to this:

```
$fp = stream_socket_client(
'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
```

Which is very strange because the exact same code is on another two php pages and it works perfectly.

I also copied and pasted the exact same code from one page where it was working to a brand new one and it didn't work... I don't see how that can make sense!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely your script is not seeing the certificates, it could be as simple as the wrong path to the certificate key.

Putting the full path to the certificate is a good idea.

Comment: I think my paths have all been messed up by the cron job

Comment: Hi! I have the same problem... this happen when  update xampp version.
I put full path to .pem file, but the problem persist.